# How to use Seaborn color palette by column in plt.subplots?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm plotting Seaborn regplots as subplots and want that the color palette of each row is the same.

I'm doing a Design of Experiment analysis on Python, and have issues with the plotting of the interaction effects with Seaborn.

I want the colour-pairs on each row to be the same, but I can't find a way to do it through the matplotlib or seaborn methods. I tried the 'with sns.color_palette()' and the 'ax.set_prop_cycle()' suggestions from other questions, but the Figure displays the same as without them.

This generates the Dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools as it

encoded_inputs = list( it.product([-1, 1], [-1, 1], [-1, 1]) )
doe = pd.DataFrame(encoded_inputs, columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3'])
doe['y1'] = doe.apply( lambda z : sum([ np.random.rand()*z["x%d"%(i)]+0.01*(0.5-np.random.rand()) for i in range(1,3) ]), axis=1)
print(doe)
```

This generates the Figure with the subplots:

```py
factors = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
f, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(12, 12))

for i in range(len(factors)):
    for j in range(len(factors)):
        yy = factors[j]

        with sns.color_palette('Paired'):
            sns.regplot(x=factors[i], y='y1', data=doe[doe[yy]==-1], label='-1', x_estimator=np.mean, ci=None, truncate=True, ax=axs[j,i])
            sns.regplot(x=factors[i], y='y1', data=doe[doe[yy]==1], label='1', x_estimator=np.mean, ci=None, truncate=True, ax=axs[j,i])

        axs[j,i].legend(title=yy,facecolor='white')

        if i==j:
            axs[j,i].clear()

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set_ylabel(None)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The actual result is that the color palette cycles through all the subplots in the order of drawing. 
I'd like to be able to reset the color palette iterator as I begin to draw the subplots of a new column, or to sync the colours of two subplots.